# Exception was thrown when adding new rows to datatable

Tags: vb.net, linq, .net-3.5, datatable

- listA is list of integer
- dtListB is DataTable

I'm checking that if StudentId of ListA doesn't exist in  dtListB, then add it to the dtListB.

Dim stidListA, stIdListB As Integer

```
    For Each la In listA
        stidListA = la.StudentId

        For n = 0 To dtListB.Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
            stIdListB = dtListB.Rows(n)("StudentId")
            If stIdListB <> stidListA Then
    dtListB.Rows.Add(New Object() {la.StudentId, la.AssignedId, la.TimeSheetId, 0})
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

I'm not sure why the error is thrown :

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

**dtListB.Rows.Add(New Object() {la.StudentId, la.AssignedId, la.TimeSheetId, 0})**

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: i'm not a VB.net person but that error seems to me like your loop is infinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't really checking `if StudentId of ListA doesn't exist in dtListB`. What your code actually does is it compares **EVERY** element in `dtListB` with the current element from `ListA` and if in case they are not the same, it adds a new row to dtListB. So assume you have the following lists:

```
ListA = { 3, 4 };
dtListB = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

The first iteration for `ListA`, value is `3`.

```
Check: (3 <> 1) and add '3' to dtListB (dtListB = { 1, 2, 3, 3 })
Check: (3 <> 2) and add '3' to dtListB (dtListB = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 3 })
Check: (3 <> 3) and don't do anything.
(Since the list has grown, you have two more iterations)
```

For the second iteration for `ListA` with value `4` you will insert it 5 times for every element of the existing array you compare with, and get the resulting list: `{ 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 }`. Obviously that's not the result you are expecting, and you probably have larger lists and run out of memory.

I would suggest keeping a `Boolean` flag `itemFound` when looping through `dtListB`. Set it to `False` before the loop and if a matching item is encountered, set it to `True`. After the loop, check if `itemFound` is `False` and if so, add the item to the list. This probably isn't  valid VB syntax, but you get the idea:

```
For Each la In listA
    stidListA = la.StudentId

    Dim itemFound as Boolean = False

    For n = 0 To dtListB.Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
        stIdListB = dtListB.Rows(n)("StudentId")
        If stIdListB <> stidListA Then
            itemFound = True
            Break //(is there Break in VB?)
        End If
    Next

    If Not itemFound Then
        dtListB.Rows.Add(New Object() {la.StudentId, la.AssignedId, la.TimeSheetId, 0})
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Yes, declaring a variable for item found is easy for manipulating the datatable later on. Anyway, there's no Break but Exit For in VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating with `dtListB.Rows` and inserting into `dtListB.Rows`. It is increasing the `Count` and just looping for an indeterminate amount of time.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have to move dtListB.Rows.Add out of the its loop.